# git config core.autocrlf is true, but I'm still getting a warning?

Tags: git, git-bash, line-endings, core.autocrlf

I understand that Windows uses CRLF and that it's good practice to let Git change line endings to LF before committing and back to CRLF when checking out. For that reason, I have `core.autocrlf` set to true. However, contrary to what other threads say (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important)), I am still getting this warning:

> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in [FILE_NAME].
>   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

Firstly, I thought setting `core.autocrlf` to true was supposed to stop these warnings. Secondly, isn't Git supposed to convert LF to CRLF when committing, not the other way around?

Interestingly, I just committed many files and got this warning for only two of them (a .csproj and a .cs).

P.S. I am using Git Bash on Windows.

Comment: Does [Customizing Git — Git Configuration](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) and the section on `core.whitespace` immediately after the section on `core.autocrlf` provide any insight or help?  How did you check that you have `core.autocrlf` set correctly?

Comment: I ran `git config core.autocrlf` and it printed `true`.

Answer (score 3):

> that it's good practice to let Git change line endings to LF before committing and back to CRLF when checking out.

It is, but *not* with core.autocrlf.
You should always set core.autocrlf to false, as it would try and convert eol (end of line) for *all* files (including non-text file)

If you have files that need conversion, use an [`eol` directive in a `.gitattributes` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19263845/6309).
Make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) though: there was a [bug in Git 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575761/6309).

That being said, if you still want to use `core.autocrlf`, see "[Make Git “LF will be replaced by CRLF” warnings go away](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599574/6309)": you can remove your index and checkout again.

Comment: Still, why is it replacing LF with CRLF when adding to index? I thought it was supposed to be the opposite.

Comment: @Farshid Not sure: I know of https://stackoverflow.com/a/14039909/6309. What Git version are you using? the last one 2.13? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) What command are you doing to trigger that warning message?

Comment: @Farshid Do you have any .gitattributes in your repo, as seen in https://github.com/git/git/commit/15c96723457cfa1be6cdbd74e3131ecf13cd9790? That would explain the message if an eol directove were to force the eol to LF.

Comment: I have `* text=auto` in .gitattributes

Comment: I'm using 2.11.1. I need to update it. The command is `git add`, or `git commit -a`, which runs `add` itself.

Comment: @Farshid The warning might come from the .gitattributes directive. Yes, can you try and see with Git 2.13 first?