# Git pull on Windows (git smc client) doesn't respect .gitattributes's eol=lf

Tags: git, line-endings, lf

I am working on a project originally developed in Unix environment.

Such project has a .gitattributes file with forcing eol=lf over standard crlf-lf conversion

`*.sh text eol=lf`

which is my understanding is telling git "keep the original LF line endings".

When I clone this repository, in the moment the pull is complete, If I do `git status`, some files are marked as changed already (specifically .sh files)

`git diff` shows

```
-FileContent
+FileContent
```

where FileContent is all the text in the file.

I tried to:

- git reset --hard
- git update-index --assume-unchanged
- git config --global core.autocrlf false
- git config --global core.eol lf
- `dos2unix` on single files
- changing line endings for specifi files to \n with my editor (Phpstorm)

None had effect on the issue.

I also tried:

- git rm --cached -rf . -> this deleted a lot of files in the project
- to re-fetch a specific branch ( `git fetch; git checkout HEAD path/)
- git add --renormalize . -> all the .sh files appear as modified (it was only 1 after refetching the file from the branch following the above configuration)
- git diff --ignore-all-space shows nothing
- `od path/file.sh` shows a binary version of the file (before setting the above configuration was actually text)

**How can I make git respect the `eol=of` value for `.sh` files?**

---

**Edit**: after removing the index via `rm .git/index` and performing `git reset --hard HEAD`, the problem was gone

Also (for reference): didn't try
-  core.autocrlf to false

Comment: A bit confused @dragonmnl : Here you say autocrlf is not false. In comments below vonc answer you say it is.

Comment: Coming from the future to confirm that, to me also, `git add --renormalize .` was doing the opposite of what I wanted (was converting everything to crlf). `rm .git/index` followed by `git reset --hard HEAD` (with `autocrlf = false`) was what made the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding eol conversion:

1. Make sure core.autocrlf is set to false (that way, only `[.gitattributes` directives][1](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion) will be in play)
2. Use `text eol=lf`
3. Follows by `git add --renormalize .` to force the application of the .gitattributes directives. ([since Git 2.16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309), Q1 2018)

> after removing the index via `rm .git/index` and performing `git reset --hard HEAD`, the problem was gone

That is what `git add --renormalize .` is supposed to emulate.

Comment: --renormalize seems to make things worse (I updated my question)

Comment: @dragonmnl worse? Or actually like you want them (with lf at the end)?

Comment: the remote repo was created on unix systems so all files should have LF endings. The issue I am having is that files appear changed (in spite of .gitattributes) and so they must be included in a commit to be marked as changed

It's the warning git gives <<LF will be converted to CRLF>>

Comment: @dragonmnl Do you have `core.autocrlf` set to `false`? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9094476/6309)

Comment: I do. I checked with `git config --list`

Comment: @dragonmnl What version of Git are you using? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44224929/6309)

Comment: git version 2.27.0.windows.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215916/discussion-between-vonc-and-dragonmnl).