# .gitattributes not respected on most windows OS

Tags: git, eol, gitattributes

So I've tried to introduce a `.gitattributes` file to my projects repos but I've run into an issue where the file is not respected among some of my peers Windows 10 machines. I've tried looking at [Git pull on Windows (git smc client) doesn't respect .gitattributes's eol=lf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62367256/git-pull-on-windows-git-smc-client-doesnt-respect-gitattributess-eol-lf) and many other posts to no avail as it doesn't fit the experience I am seeing. I would expect given this `.gitattributes` file that all text would stay as LF but it is not. The windows OS is actively converting the files at `git add` (which have all undergone `git add --renormalize .`) to CRLF. The exact warning is: `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Callflows/ors_PostCreateOrsIssue.callflow. The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.`

To confound it more, a couple of my peers' windows OS performs as expected where the LF and the `.gitattributes` is respected.

Gitattributes:

```
# Setting a default value and trusting git to do correctly determine files
*               text eol=LF

# Java sources
*.java          text diff=java
*.gradle        text diff=java
*.gradle.kts    text diff=java

# These files are text and should be normalized (Convert crlf => lf)
*.css           text diff=css
*.df            text
*.htm           text diff=html
*.html          text diff=html
*.js            text
*.jsp           text
*.jspf          text
*.jspx          text
*.properties    text
*.tld           text
*.tag           text
*.tagx          text
*.xml           text
*.grxml         text
*.callflow      text
*.json          text

# These files are binary and should be left untouched
# (binary is a macro for -text -diff)
*.class         binary
*.dll           binary
*.ear           binary
*.jar           binary
*.so            binary
*.war           binary
*.jks           binary
*.wav           binary
*.vox           binary
*.gram          binary
```

Here is a **working** setup from my peers machine.

- `git --version`: 2.18.0.windows.1
- global git config retrieved using `git config -l`.

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/asdf/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
user.name=asdf
user.email=asdf@asdf.com
difftool.sourcetree.cmd='' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=''
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
```

Setup from a peer where it is **NOT working**:

- `git --version`: 2.18.0.windows.1
- `git config -l`:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misconfigured your `.gitattributes` file.  The attribute is `eol=lf`, not `eol=LF`.  This option is case sensitive, like most Git options, and by specifying `LF` this attribute is left unset.  Since it's unset and your version of Git is configured with `core.autocrlf=true`, your files are checked out as CRLF.

If you fix that, things should work correctly.

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense! I'll try that out in the morning. Any reason it would work on one persons machine where they also have `core.autocrlf=true`?

Comment: That message only occurs if your editor writes LF endings and CRLF are expected, so maybe they have their editor configured differently.